# How to get category name by multiple id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, name

I want to get category name using multiple category ids.

I have two category id like :- 3 or 4.Those two id using i am want to category name.

Please help me how to achieve this.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: for example?? What ids do you have? is it in an array or what? Maybe explain a little bit more.

Comment: @KlausMikaelson i have update my question. please check. **Thanks**

Comment: You may already have checked this but still https://stackoverflow.com/a/38692903 .

Comment: yes,But how to use multiple id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace Company\Module\Block;

class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $_categoryFactory;    

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    ) {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCategoryName($catIds)
    {
        $catNames = [];
        foreach ($catIds as $key => $catId) {
         $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($catId);
         $catNames[$catId] = $category->getName();
        }
        return $catNames;
    }
    
    public function getAllCatName()
    {
      $catIds = array(3,4);
      $categoryNames = $this->getCategoryName($catIds);
      print_r($categoryNames);die;
    }
}
```

In phtml file you can call `$block->getAllCatName()`; Or if you have ids 3,4 in array phtml like `$catIds = array(3,4);` you can directly call `$categoryNames = $block->getCategoryName($catIds);`

Comment: Yes,this answer help me. **THANKS**

Comment: Hi, How to get product collection by multiple category id.

Comment: I will check that also in my free time. But you should ask a new question. Someone will give the answer surely. People will not come here and see your comment but they will see new questions so that would get you a fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

where you need to get the categories name? phtml? block? Model?

for example, in a phtml file you can inject a viewModel and in that class you can get the categories name.

To get the categories name by multiple ids, you can made a collection filtering by entity_id and selecting only the "name" attribute, or you can instantiate the CategoryRepository and with a loop you can load the categoryModel for every id.

Comment: yes, i want to category name in phtml file.But how ?

Comment: please can you add php code?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so you need to edit the layout xml (if you need this info on the product page, you need to edit the catalog_product_view.xml). Find the block tag and add this code:

`<arguments><argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\ViewModelFolder\ViewModelClass</argument></arguments>`

This class must implement the ArgumentInterface.

In his constructor you can instantiate a CategoryRepository class, like:

```
protected $categoryRespository;

public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository) 
{
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
}
```

Or you can instantiate the CollectionFactory:

```
protected $categoryCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
}
```

After this you need to create a method that accept an array with the ids:

```
public function getCategoryNameByIds(array $ids = [])
{
    $names = [];
    //for categoryRepository
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($id);
        $names[$id] = $category->getName();
    }

    //for collectionFactory
    $categoryCollection = $categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $categoryCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', [in => $ids]);

    // either call getItems() and iterate over it, or do whatever you need
    foreach ($categoryCollection->getItems() as $category) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
        $names[$category->getId()] = $category->getName();
    }
    return $names;
}
```